# package /usr/bin/dpkg problem when install anything

Tags: dpkg

```
(>= 0.8.5~ubuntu1).
 python3-aptdaemon depends on python3-dbus.
 python3-aptdaemon depends on python3-gi.

dpkg: error processing package python3-aptdaemon (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of aptdaemon:
 aptdaemon depends on gir1.2-glib-2.0.
 aptdaemon depends on python3-aptdaemon (= 1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu16~ubuntu16.04~ppa1); however:
  Package python3-aptdaemon is not configured yet.
 aptdaemon depends on python3-gi; however:

dpkg: error processing package aptdaemon (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets:
 python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets depends on python3-aptdaemon (= 1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu16~ubuntu16.04~ppa1); however:
  Package python3-aptdaemon is not configured yet.
 python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets depends on python3-gi; however:
 python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets depends on gir1.2-gtk-3.0; however:
 python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets depends on gir1.2-vte-2.91; however:

dpkg: error processing package python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 adapta-gtk-theme
 nautilus-data
 nautilus
 paper-gtk-theme
 python3-aptdaemon
 aptdaemon
 python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

my ubuntu version is 16.4

Comment: Try `sudo apt -f install`

Comment: i test it, that's same error

Comment: what did you do before this error?

Comment: try sudo apt-get install python3-dbus python3-gi

Comment: i gave same error

Comment: You seem to have unwisely installed software that is *incompatible* with your release of Ubuntu. Only you know what that software may be. Uninstall the incompatible software, and delete the PPA or other non-Ubuntu source it came from.